# Decoding a TCP stream using ffmpeg

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I am using the Ffmpeg library in an Android application I am writing. I have written the code to open up a local file and decode that using avformat_open_input(). However I need to use Ffmpeg to read in a video stream over TCP. I have found a few things within Ffmpeg such as libavcodec/tcp.h but I can't establish how to actually open up a TCP stream into the decoder.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to connect directly through the ffmpeg api you might be able to set up a connection externally and write the inbound data to a pipe. The ffmpeg library should be able to read from this pipe as you would a normal file.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740321/how-to-create-named-pipe-mkfifo-in-android) regarding how to set up the pipe.